# ValueError while processing two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to sample from beta distribution for multiple pair of alpha and beta.
So I loaded those alpha and beta in arrays `a` and `b` and tried calculating it in parallel as follows:

```
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = np.array([3,2,4,2,6])
>>> import random
>>> random.betavariate(a+1,b+1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 679, in betavariate
    y = self.gammavariate(alpha, 1.0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/random.py", line 564, in gammavariate
    if alpha <= 0.0 or beta <= 0.0:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

As you can see, I ended up getting error. Is it because `random.betavariate()` expects alpha and beta not to be numpy lists?

Next, I tried following:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x,y : random.betavariate(x,y),a,b))
[0.06403096830025037, 0.48396460498711924, 0.2652080357595285, 0.4468980529245114, 0.8550096603254491]
```

And it worked? So, do I have to explicitly use map to call `random.betavariate()` on list of alpha-beta-pairs? If yes, wont it be slower than numpy parallelization? In fact is it possible to correctly implement my first code to make numpy parallelly compute them?

PS: I am python 3.8.2

Answer (score 1):

use random from numpy instead

```py
from numpy.random import default_rng
rng = default_rng()
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
b = np.array([3,2,4,2,6])
rng.beta(a+1,b+1)
```

Comment: how do we set seed when making call `default_rng`? Like this: `np.random.default_rng(seed=1)`?  Also how it differs from `numpy.random.beta` ?

Comment: you are right.[docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generator.html#numpy.random.default_rng)